# KendoUI Column Center Custom MVC Extension Method

Tags: css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, extension-methods, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am looking for a way to create a custom extension method for a KendoUI column that will allow me to easily add a css class to the header or the cell itself using an extension method.

Right now i'm using the following to center the contents of both the header and the cell:

```
columns.Bound(x => x.Value).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "cent" }).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "cent" });
```

where the cent css class is:

```
.cent { text-align:center; }
```

To me this seems like alot of code to write for something this simple.

What i am looking for is a solution to create a custom column builder extension method where i can just do something like this:

```
columns.Bound(x => x.Value).CenterHeader().CenterCell();
```

Where the CenterHeader() and CenterCell() would be custom extension methods that would add this css class to the header and cell respectively. The code would look much cleaner if this were possible IMO.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just create these extensions?

```
using Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static GridTemplateColumnBuilder<T> CenterHeader<T>(this GridTemplateColumnBuilder<T> builder) where T : class
        {
            return builder.HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "cent" });
        }

        .....
    }
}
```

And add this namespace (so that you shouldn't import it all the time) in `Views/web.config`:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      ......
      <add namespace="Kendo.Mvc.UI"/>
      <add namespace="MyNamespace"/>
      ......
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```